# How to run minikube on ubuntu 22.04 and docker 17.03.0-ce

Tags: minikube, ubuntu-22.04, docker-engine

I'm trying to run minikube with docker on an os ubuntu but when I run the command `minikube start --driver=docker` I get the following error:

```
Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset1828696490 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker cp --help'.
: exit status 125

❌  Exiting due to GUEST_PROVISION_CP_PUBKEY: Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: prepare kic ssh: copying pub key: docker copy /tmp/tmpf-memory-asset1828696490 into minikube:/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys, output: unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker cp --help'.
: exit status 125
```

or when I run another command like `minikube start --vm`
gives the following error:

```
Failed to start docker container. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: provision: Temporary Error: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

❌  Exiting due to IF_SSH_AUTH: Failed to start host: provision: Temporary Error: NewSession: new client: new client: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

It looks like an authentication error in ssh does anyone know how to help me?

Comment: could u also please add the version of docker and minikube? have you tried reinstalling/docker prune?

Comment: Docker version 17.03.0-ce and minikube version: v1.26.1. I tried to reinstall the docker engine but it didn't work thanks!

Comment: interesting, not too sure what else i can help other than to reinstall the minikube as well, if you are still stucked.. are all settings on default straight out of box?

Comment: I've already reinstalled minikube and nothing, see the sujeção that gives:

Comment:   Suggestion: Your host is failing to route packets to the minikube VM. If you have VPN software, try turning it off or configuring it so that it does not re-route traffic to the VM IP. If not, check your VM environment routing options.
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3930